# GC graph shows there is a memory leak but unable to track in the dump

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

We have a Java Micorservice in our application which is connected to Postgres as well as Phoenix. We are using Spring Boot 2.x.

The problem is we are executing endurance testing for our application for about 8 hours and we could observe that the used heap is keep on increasing though we used the recommended suggestions for VM arguments, looks like a memory leak. we analysed the heap dump however the root cause is not exactly clear for us, can some experts help based on the results?

The VM arguments that we are actually using are:

> -XX:ConcGCThreads=8 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:InitialHeapSize=536870912 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=45 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:MaxHeapSize=536870912 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=16 -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:StringDeduplicationAgeThreshold=1 -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication

We are expecting the used heap should be flat in the GC log, however memory consumption is not released and it keeps on increasing.

Heap Dump:
[image]

GC graph:
[image]

Comment: “*we used the recommended suggestions for VM arguments*” who suggested you these arguments based on what rationale? Did they say “these are the magic arguments that make every application run better than with the defaults”? But anyway, as long as you didn’t encounter an `OutOfMemoryError`, there is no reason to assume that there is a memory leak. In facts, the absence of such error disproves that “the used heap is keep on increasing”.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, those are not recommended suggestions by any experts,  but based on multiple runs and observations we had along with the definitions provided in the documentations,  we come to a conclusion that this should be the appropriate combinations which we can use for better execution.

Comment: You also stated "there is no reason to assume that there is a memory leak."  but what if we continue our executions for 24 hours and the used heap is heading towards top, will there be a time that it will reach its maximum limit and chance for full GC. We also observe that (in a different run) even after full GC only part of the heap memory is released. Now there is a possibility for out of memory isnt it?

Comment: It’s the normal behavior that some memory is allocated permanently and some memory is allocated and released. This doesn’t preclude that the permanently allocated memory contains some objects you don’t want keep, but as long as the permanently allocated memory doesn’t raise up to the point that the application fails (e.g. with an `OutOfMemoryError`), you don’t have a serious problem. And we can’t see from the memory stats, whether there are unwanted objects. Not even the heapdump (not to speak of a screenshot) would help, as we don’t know which objects are supposed to be there and which not.

Comment: Thanks a lot Holger,  we are now in a situation to get a decent GC graph using IHOP and Newratio. Used heap is getting released better than earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which tool you are using above, but I would be looking for the dominator hierarchy in the heap. [Eclipse MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) is a good tool to analyse heap dumps and it can point you in the direction of what's actually holding the memory and you can decide if you want to categorise it as a leak or not. Regardless of the label you attach, if the application is going to crash after a while because it runs out of memory, then it is a problem.

This [blog](https://medium.com/illegalarguments/how-to-find-memory-leaks-in-spring-boot-592faf11d571?source=friends_link&sk=4899a391d673851be6342c37c52daecc) also discusses diagnosing this type of problems.